# Stop Parallels Desktop from opening mac excel when trying to open the virtual machines copy

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, parallels

Im using Parallels Desktop 8 to allow me to run Windows 7 on my Macbook, i use it mostly for browser testing IE, and running certain vba macros which will not run in mac Excel 2011.

Whenever i try and open an excel file in the virtual machine it opens it in the mac version of excel, the way i get around this is to open windows excel and use file > open.

Is there a way to set it to default open in the native version.. ie. opened in Windows run it in windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your defaults check out this link http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v9/ga/docs/ko_KR/Parallels%20Desktop%20User's%20Guide/32927.htm

I just use the right click method.